# keycloak : Too many redirects with remember me checked

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

My application is integrated with Keycloak authentication and works fine. When the application is logged in with  **remember-me** checkbox checked, 
I expect the scenario working like:

> ```
>     - User logged with "rememberMe" checkbox on
>     - User closed the browser
>     - User re-open the browser can access the application directly without asking for the credential, till the user session is valid
> ```

But the **current scenario** is:

When user re-open the browser and tried to access the application, its showing **too many redirects** in browser. wildfly log says: ***Account was not in session, returning null , there was no code***

Any idea about too many redirects ?

Comment: do you have any http trace (anonymized) ? One way this could happen is if your application listen only on http and cookies are flagged `secure`

Comment: My application is listen only to http but the cookies are not flagged secure